# Rails: How to get items in drop down select list to connect to a form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want a logged in user to vote on a topic.

Asking the user to input a vote into a text field works fine:

```
_form.html.erb

   ...............
   <p>
     <h1 style="color:red;"> Register your vote </h1>
     <%= form_for @topic do |t| %>
     <%=t.label :"#{current_user.name}_vote".to_sym%>
     <%= t.text_field  :"#{current_user.name}_vote".to_sym%>
     <%= t.submit "Submit Vote", class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg" %>
   </p>
   ..............
```

But this would be improved by selection from a dropdown list.

I can get a list by:

```
<select name=#{current_user.name}_vote">
   <%= @votes.each do |vote| %>
    <option value="<%= vote %>"><%= vote %></option>
   <% end %>
</select>
```

But I have failed to find how to connect it to the form, so I get the error "param is missing or the value is empty: topic"

I've spent ages working at this without success.  I am am rank beginner in rails. Please help if you can. Thank you.

Comment: does your `Topic` model have `name=#{current_user.name}_vote"` field? That is separate column for each user. I don't think so.

Comment: Yes it does there are only 8 users.  If it didn't, I don't think the non-dropdown version would work?

Comment: ok it was just some clarification

Comment: is your select wrapped in form?

Comment: what is `@votes` ?

Comment: votes is an array of allowable votes(strings)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to wrap `select` in `form`.

```
<%= form_for @topic do |t| %>
  <select name=#{current_user.name}_vote">
    <%= @votes.each do |vote| %>
      <option value="<%= vote %>"><%= vote %></option>
    <% end %>
  </select>
<% end %>
```

It would be better to use `select` Rails helper.

Comment: I had already tried that,  My code from <select ......</select> is in a partial "_choices.html.erb" and I had tried <%= render 'choices'%> wrapped in that way earlier today.

Comment: maybe you can add plain html to your question? you can open debug console in browser and copy some source code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

inside your form:

```
<p>
     <h1 style="color:red;"> Register your vote </h1>
     <%= form_for @topic do |t| %>
     <%=t.label :"#{current_user.name}_vote".to_sym%>
     <%= t.text_field  :"#{current_user.name}_vote".to_sym%>
     <%= t.select :"#{current_user.name}_vote".to_sym, options_for_select(@votes.map{ |v| [v.your_desired_field,v.id }) %>

     <%= t.submit "Submit Vote", class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg" %>
   </p>
```

`your_desired_field` should be the attribute of the `vote` that will be option text.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to `_form.html.erb`:

```
<%= f.select  "#{current_user.name}_vote".to_sym, options_for_select(@votes) %>
```

Comment: @user2900160 If it has solved your problem, can you accept it as answer ? It might help someone else.